# VSTS extension - several questions (data storage and React)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

1. I've been using the VSTS data storage. Can the data storage be shared with other users? I thought this would be possible, but when I tried to fetch documents with the same ID from another account, it seemed to be not working. How can other user look at the data added from my side? (Project-level Global data storage?)
2. Is there a way to use React to develop a VSTS extension? If so, how can I set it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the answer is yes. Just set the data scopeType to Project Collection when create the data.

Refer to this link for details: [How you can scope data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts#how-you-can-scope-data).

> Settings and document collections can be scoped to either the:
>
> 1. Project Collection: shared by all users of the project collection to
>      which the extension is installed
> 2. User: a single user of a project
>      collection to which the extension is installed

For React, check this sample for reference: [Visual Studio Team Services Office UI Fabric React Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/ui-fabric-react).

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured out how to do #1 a few days ago. Now I have a new problem. I am trying access the name of the current VSTS project, but using `VSS.getWebContext()` doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Dawn17 I just tested it, it works at my side. Where and when did you call that method?

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790867/function-works-when-i-put-it-in-an-onclick-but-doesnt-work-when-i-try-to-use-in?noredirect=1#comment90540183_51790867

Comment: And also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755803/how-to-make-data-storage-unique-to-project-in-vsts-extension/51763448#51763448 If I put inside an onclick function, it works. But when I try to call it onload, it doesnt.