# How to make data storage unique to project in VSTS extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

```
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData)
    // the callback on the next line returns a promise, which the JavaScript engine will follow, so you don't need to nest the next `then`
        .then((dataService) => dataService.getDocuments('MyCollection2'))
        .then((docs) => { ...
```

This is how we access data storage in VSTS extension.
`MyCollection2` is a name of the storage that we are using.
However, this is not unique to the project. When I try to access the hub extension from another project within the same organization, I can still see the data.

I tried to dynamically name the collection based on the project that I access, but there is no clear way to get the project name on the extension side.

How can I make the data storage unique to the project within the same organization??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed this by using a Promise.

```
    // Sets unique data storage name for each project
    function setDBName() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

                VSS.ready(function(){
                    let web = VSS.getWebContext();
                    resolve(web);
                })
        })
    }
```

then

```
    setDBName()
        .then(function(res){
            console.log('res', res)
        }
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('err', err)
        }
```

This will return the web context whenever VSS is ready to get fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You could get project name from [getWebContext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=vsts#getwebcontext()). Then set the DocumentId value to the ProjectName:

```
// Get data service
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
        // Set value (default is project collection scope)
        dataService.setValue("ProjectName", "DocumentId").then(function(value) {
            console.log("Key value is " + value);
        });
    });
```

After that, retrieve the setting value:

```
// Get data service
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
        // Get value in user scope
        dataService.getValue("ProjectName").then(function(value) {
            console.log("User scoped key value is " + value);
        });
    });
```

Last, when you get the document from the DocumentId, it will get from a project:

```
// Get data service
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
        // Get document by id
        dataService.getDocument("MyCollection", "DocumentId").then(function(doc) {
            // Assuming document has a property named foo
            console.log("Doc foo: " + doc.foo); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense but whenever I use `VSS.getWebContext()`, it gives me an `undefined`. I did if after `VSS.init();`

Comment: I've also tried to use `__vssPageContext`. This is accessible when I try to console it from the VSTS page, but when I just put it in code like `console.log(__vssPageContext)` it says `undefined`.

Comment: How about put it in `vss.ready`: `VSS.ready(function () {VSS.GetWebContext });`?

Comment: Dong Still says undefined. Weirdly, it works when I put it into an onclick function. But I want to use it onload.

Comment: @Dawn17 Where do you use the extension and call getWebContext()? Such as Build Summary or Work Hub and so no?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT  do in in the hub extension that i've created.