# Function works when I put it in an onclick but doesn't work when I try to use in on page-load (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am building a Microsoft VSTS extension using `HTML` `JavaScript`.

I need to access this function `VSS.getWebContext()` which gives you all information of the project page where you are currently running your extension.

```
let webContext = VSS.getWebContext();
let projectName = webContext.project.name + "_kpi_test"

# prints out fine
console.log('projname', projectName);
```

When I put this into an `onclick` function of a `button`, it works fine and prints the information that I need.

But when I just use

```
    $(window).ready(function(){
        // your code
    });
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // your code
    });
```

and

```
window.onload = codeAddress; //my function here
```

to use the `VSS.getWebContext()` to retrieve the information when the page loads, it keeps giving me that `VSS.getWebContext()` is `undefined`.

If it works on onClick but not on page-load, what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know exactly what VSTS is but jquery's document ready is built specifically to be executable as soon as the document is manipulatable, not when the page is fully complete.  have you tried putting it in a while loop and re executing until it's not defined?

Comment: Do you mean something like `while(VSS.getWebContext() !== undefined) { //do something }`? I just tried but it also never gets loaded.

Comment: your best bet is to use the 'load' event with `window.addEventListener('load', codeAddress)`

Comment: what does your entire code look like when it doesn't work?

Comment: @dawn i mean the opposite. `let webContext; while(webContext === undefined) webContext = VSS.getWebContext();`

Comment: If you put this inside a `while` and it never gets a value, then your page will freeze inside an infinite loop

Comment: true. use setTimeout to push next tick

Comment: @bcr666 I just put `let webContext = VSS.getWebContext();` `console.log(webContext)` inside them.

Comment: Where are you importing VSS?

Comment: @bcr666 Same page. I do `<script src="lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly VSS needs, but since it is working in onClick it is probably just that the page has not actually completely loaded yet in your document and window ready calls.

You could try:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `VSS.init` and `VSS.ready` function, see [use the SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/master/README.md#use-the-sdk) from **vss-web-extension-sdk** GitHub for more information.

#### In Angular & TypeScript:

```
  // VARIABLES VSS
  extensionInitializationOptions: IExtensionInitializationOptions = { applyTheme: false, usePlatformScripts: false, usePlatformStyles: false };

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    if (environment.production) {
      // VSS INIT
      VSS.init(this.extensionInitializationOptions);

      // VSS READY
      VSS.ready(async () => {
        await this.init();
      });
    } else await this.init();
  }
```

`environment.production` for local debugging.